# JavaFx TabPane getScene() or getParent() returns null

Tags: java, javafx

I noticed that executing `getScene()` on nodes placed inside a `TabPane` returns `null`. Also `getParent()` returns `null`.

I need to call `getScene()` for a dialog which opens from a node in the hierarchy.

As an example my hierarchy is like this:

```
Stage-Scene-SplitPane-TabPane-Tab-TextArea
```

Inside textArea I open an `Alert` and call

```
myAlert.initOwner( textArea.getScene());
```

`textArea.getScene()` returns `null`, so the dialog shows on a different monitor (bad position and does not inherit css ).
How may I avoid this?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue. Please add a [mcve]. The issue could be the time when you retrieve the properties: If you access those properties before the `TabPane` skin is created, those values return `null` since the content has not yet been added as descendant of the `TabPane`. The skin should be created when the stage containing the `TabPane` is shown...

Comment: You are right. I have been creating a new tab, adding it to the tabPane and then showing the dialog in one single thread. I added Platform.runLater() when calling the dialog, and now everything works fine.